# Unable to connect to db after passing arguments. Getting error as Invalid argument values

Tags: perl

After compilation I am getting error as . It is printing user , name and password detail after that getting error as.

failed: invalid argument value. Cannot connect to db.

Even after passing the correct argument value it is taking only space and not the details which were passed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

use DBI;

sub routine {
  my (%data) = @_;

  my $user = $data{'db2_user'};

  my $name = $data{'db2_name'};

  my $password= $data{'db2_passwd'};

  print $user. "\n". $name "\n". $password. "\n";

  my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI: DB2: $name", "$user", "$password") 
    or die ("Cannot connect to DB");

}

# Main function

my $config_file;
my $details_file;

# Check number of argument on command line
if (@ARGV == 2) {
  $config_file=$ARGV[0];
  $details_file=$ARGV[1];
}
else {
  die "Usage

  The script reads two <config file>";
}

open (my $input_fh, "<", $details_file)
  or die "Cannot open config file: $!";

my %data;

while (my $line = <$input_fh>) {
  chomp $line;

  if ($line =~  /^(\w+)\s\*=\s*(.*)$/) {
    $data{$1} = $2;
  }
}

close $input_fh;

routine (%data);

exit 0;
```

Comment: I've formatted your code section as code. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself next time. It's possible that I've left extra escaping `\\` characters in the code. Please check and feel free to correct any errors I've made.

Comment: I am still a beginner . Thanks for suggestions I'll definitely consider these next time.

Comment: Perl tip: You can put variables directly in a double-quoted string - `print "$user\n$name\n$password\n";`

Comment: Debugging tip: When printing out variable values, always include delimiters so you can spot excess whitespace - `print "<$user>\n<$name>\n<$password>\n";`

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for DBD::DB2](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBD-DB2/view/DB2.pod) shows the connection string like this:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:DB2:db_name", $username, $password);
```

Is there any reason why you changed it to have a slightly different format? Converting it to match your code, it would be:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:DB2:$name", $user, $password)
  or die ("Cannot connect to DB");
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but after trying this code change I am still getting error as : DBI connect (' ', ' ', ...) failed: A database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE= 08003

Comment: @Coder: Can you update your question to add the current version of your code, along with the contents of the two input files. Maybe check that you're pulling the connection information from the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$line =~  /^(\w+)\s\*=\s*(.*)$/
```

This regular expression only matches lines like

```
'foo *=bar'
```

which is probably not what you intended.

You have escaped the asterisk, which means it's looking for a literal asterisk.

You probably wanted `/^(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/` instead.